# Отступы вверху страницы

Tags: php, html, css

### Не могу понять откуда отступ вверху страницы

.CSS

```
* {
    font-family: calibri;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    background: white;
}
.button {
    font-size: 3vw;
    border-color: #caa54c;
    background: #caa54c;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:auto;
}
.requestbox {
    font-size: 3vw;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-color:#3d3d3d;
    margin:auto;
}
A:link { text-decoration: none; color:white; /* Убирает подчеркивание для ссылок */ } 
A:visited { text-decoration: none; color:white;} 
A:active { text-decoration: none; }
A:hover { text-decoration: none; color: silver; }
```

При просмотре кода страницы заметил следующее:
[image: код страницы]

Теги вставляются через .php. 10 раз уже все перепроверил. Эта комбинация цифр нигде не встречается.

Comment: Сохраните файлы без бом, в обычном UTF8.

Comment: А что такое БОМ? Итак вроде в UTF..

Comment: Через какой редактор работаете? Byte Order Mark

Comment: Прямо на домене есть возможность редактировать. Спасибо. Попробую перезалить все из блокнота.

Comment: Вы используете обычный блокнот? Насколько помню он с бомами сохраняет

Comment: Да. Перезаливка не помогла..

Comment: Используйте Sublime к примеру, там есть примерно следующее `file > Save file with encoding>Utf-8 without bom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виной всему BOM (Byte Order Mark) - символ, а точнее кодировка html документа UTF-8 BOM.

Чтобы исправить это, нужно пересохранить документ в UTF-8 без BOM.

Сделать это можно несколькими способами:

- С помощью Notepad++ или иным редактором, который может изменять кодировку документа, нужно сохранить файл в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM
- Если неизвестно, в каком файле присутствует та самая метка BOM можно воспользоваться скриптом для поиска и удаления метки BOM из документов. Сохраните следующий https://simplamarket.com/files/uploads/Blog/BOM.php.zip в корне сайта под именем BOM.php и зайдите на http://you_site.com/BOM.php (!ВАЖНО перед выполнением сделать backup)